# How to return an object that's dependent on a chain of using statements?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'd like to write a method similar to this one:

```
C Make()
{
    using (var a = new A())
    using (var b = new B(a))
    {
        return new C(b);
    }
}
```

This is bad since when the method returns, `c` keeps a reference to a disposed object.

Note that:

- `A` implements `IDisposable`.
- `B` implements `IDisposable`.
- `C` does
  NOT implement `IDisposable` since the author of `C` stated that `C`
  does not take ownership of `b`.

Comment: You don't _need_ to dispose of them - `using` does that for you.  That's the point of `using`.  Is the problem that `b` is disposed when `C` tries to use it?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to dispose of `a` and `b` until your done using `C`?

Comment: @DStanley yeah, but when using the returned variable you'll get an ObjectDisposedException (depending on the implementation). OP: if you want a disconnected scenario, you'll have to instruct the client to dispose `b`. You can do so by letting `C` do that and make `C : IDisposable`. See [Return an object created by USING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228521/) and so on.

Comment: @DStanley 'b' can't be disposed of when leaving Make() since it's being used by 'c'

Comment: The b passed into `new C(b)` will be disposed, will this pose problems for the returned C instance?

Comment: @DStanley I think OP means that whilst C doesn't take ownership of B, it might expect b not to be disposed.  I think this is simply a case where using is inappropriate, and b needs disposing by the client of Make.

Comment: @nodots Yes, C is using it's b instance throughout it's lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is very similar to what I have sometimes seen when querying the database.  In an attempt to separate the logic, you sometimes see code like this:

```
var reader = ExecuteSQL("SELECT ...");
while (reader.Read()) // <-- this fails, because the connection is closed.
{
    // process row...
}

public SqlDataReader ExecuteSQL(string sql)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
}
```

But, of course, that can't work, because by the time the `SqlDataReader` returns from the `ExecuteSQL` method, the connection is already closed (disposed).

So an alternative to the above makes use of delegates to achieve the separation of concerns, but still allowing the code to work properly:

```
ExecuteSQL(reader => {
    // write code that reads from the SqlDataReader here.
});

public void ExecuteSQL(string sql, Action<SqlDataReader> processRow)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    processRow(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, perhaps you can try something similar in your case?  Something like this:

```
MakeAndProcess(c => {
    // write code that uses C here.
    // This will work, because A and B are not disposed yet.
});

public void MakeAndProcess(Action<C> processC)
{
    using (var a = new A())
    using (var b = new B(a))
    {
        processC(new C(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example of somewhere where documentation is important. It forms part of the contract for a class.

You've already realized this, of course, since you state,

> the author of `C` stated that `C` does not take ownership of `b`.

This means that you can't achieve exactly what you're after here. What you have is probably incorrect, since `a` and `b` will be disposed immediately before the new `C` is returned.

You'll need to refactor this code somewhat. Either change `Make()` such that it takes a parameter of type `B`; the caller will remain responsible for the lifetime of `B` as well as `C`. Or write a new class that implements `IDisposable` and wraps `A`, `B` and `C` and exposes `C` through a property.

If you own type `C` you might consider modifying it to allow it optionally to take ownership of `b`. This is a fairly common pattern in .NET itself. See, for example, [XmlReaderSettings.CloseInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.closeinput(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> This is bad since I cant reference `a` and `b` from outside and dispose of them.

This is bad only if you keep references to `a` or `b`, which can be disposed from outside of your code. However, these objects are disposable, and because `C` is not creating them or getting the ownership transferred, it should take whatever it needs from `A` or `B` before finishing with the constructor, and not keep a reference to a disposable object:

```
class C {
    private readonly string x;
    private readonly int y;
    public C(B b) {
        // Using b here is OK
        x = b.X;
        y = b.Y;
        // We are done with b, so when b is disposed, C will not break
    }
}
```

> Unfortunately, `C` keeps a reference to it's `b` throughout its lifetime and expects the caller to dispose of it when `C` is no longer needed

If you have no control over `C`, make an `IDisposable` wrapper for it, take ownership of `B`, and dispose of it when `C` is no longer necessary:

```
class WrapC : IDisposable {
    private readonly B b;
    public C C { get; private set; }
    public WrapC (B b) {
        this.b = b;
        C = new C(b);
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Remove the `using` statement for `B`, and dispose of `WrapC` when you are done with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, C keeps a reference to it's b throughout it's lifetime and expects the caller to dispose of it when C is no longer needed